# Equality of unions of subsets of finite set

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\alpha_n$ be the biggest number such that there exist $\alpha_n$ subsets $M_1, \dots, M_{\alpha_n} \subseteq \{1, \dots, n\}$ with the property
\begin{equation*}
M_{i_1} \cup M_{j_1} \neq M_{i_2} \cup M_{j_2} \text{ if } \{i_1, j_1\} \neq \{i_2, j_2\}
\end{equation*}
for all $i_1, j_1, i_2, j_2 \in \{1, \dots, \alpha_n\}$.
In other words, the pairwise unions of the $M_i$ and the $M_i$ themselves are all distinct.

What do we know about this number? From some numerical testing, I know that

- $\alpha_n = n$ for $n = 1, \dots, 5$
- $\alpha_6 = 7$
- $\alpha_7 \geq 9$
- $\alpha_8 \geq 10$

Is there a closed formula for this number?
Are there lower or upper bounds?
It is easy to see that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha_n = \infty$ since $\alpha_n \geq n$.
What is the order of this convergence?

EDIT

A very simple c++ program for brute-forceing the problem can be found [here](https://github.com/mbid/subsetunion-problem). I will commit some counterexamples (i.e. program output) in the future.

Comment: If you can compute a few more values, then I'd suggest checking out the list of [integer sequences](https://oeis.org).  With what you have so far, there's too many sequences to sort through.

Comment: Something doesn't look right.  When $n=2$, let $M_1=\emptyset$, $M_2=\{1\}$, and $M_3=\{2\}$.  Then, the pairwise unions are all distinct.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: No, because $M_1 \cup M_2 = M_2\cup M_2$, although $\{1,2\}\neq \{2,2\}$. Actually, the phrasing of the condition "the pairwise unions are all distinct" does not properly reflect the given formula.

Comment: I see, you allow $i_k$ and $j_k$ to be the same.

Comment: What are your examples showing $a_6=7$, $a_7\ge9$, $a_8\ge10$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102640/upper-bound-on-union-free-hypergraph is of some relevance, although it forbids $i_k=j_k$ (but I think it's probably easy to adjust for that).

Comment: I adjusted the question to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: You can find examples [here](https://github.com/mbid/subsetunion-problem/blob/master/output/easy-results.md).

Answer (score 3):

Frankl and Furedi, Union-free hypergraphs and probability theory, Europ J Combinatorics 5 (1984) 127-131, available [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~z-furedi/PUBS/furedi_frankl_union-free-and-entropy.pdf), says

Let $F(n)$ denote the maximum number of distinct subsets of an $n$-element set such that there are no four distinct subsets $A,B,C,D$ with $A\cup B=C\cup D$. We prove that $$2^{(n-\log3)/3}-2\le F(n)\le 2^{(3n+2)/4}$$ This isn't exactly the problem under discussion here, since Martin allows $A=B$, but I figure it's a good start. It might not be hard to adapt the methods and results of Frankl-Furedi to the problem at hand.

Note that there is a lot of room between the upper and lower bounds, between (essentially) $2^{n/3}$ and $2^{3n/4}$. This suggests to me that this is a hard problem, and some of the questions Martin asks may be open.

EDIT: Work on the problem did not stop in 1984. Coppersmith and Shearer, New bounds for union-free families of sets, Electron J Combin 5 (1998) Paper 39, MR1633846 (2000g:05140), calls a family, $F$, of subsets of an $n$-set weakly union-free if $F$ does not contain four distinct sets $A,B,C,D$ with $A\cup B=C\cup D$, and strongly union-free if, in addition, $A\cup B=A\cup C$ implies $B=C$. Then $f(n)$, the maximum size of a strongly union-free family, satisfies $$2^{(0.31349+o(1))n}\le f(n)\le2^{(0.4998+o(1))n}$$

Perhaps someone else will know whether there have been more recent improvements.